# Querying a partitioned BigQuery table across multiple far-apart _PARTITIONDATE days?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a number of very big tables that are partitioned by _PARTITIONDATE which I'd like to query off of regularly in an efficient way. Each time I run the query, I only need to search across a small number of dates, but these dates will change every run and may be months/years apart from one-another.

To capture these dates, I could do `_PARTITIONDATE >= '2015-01-01'` but this is making the queries run very slow as there are millions of rows on each partition. I could also do `_PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-01-01'`, but the exact date range will change every run. What I'd like to do is something like `_PARTITIONDATE IN ("2015-03-10", "2016-01-24", "2016-22-03", "2017-06-14")` so that the query only needs to run on the dates provided, which from my testing appears to work.

The problem I'm running into is that the list of dates will change every time, requiring me to join in the list of dates in a temp table first. When doing that like this `source._PARTITIONDATE IN (datelist.date)`, it does not work and runs into an error if that's the only WHERE condition when querying a partition-required table.

Any advice for ways I might get this to work or other approach to querying off specific partitions that aren't back to back without having to process querying the whole thing?

I've been reading through the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#better_performance_with_pseudo-columns) but I don't see an answer to this question. I do see it says that the following "doesn't limit the scanned partitions, because it uses table values, which are dynamic." So possibly what I'm trying to do is impossible with the current BQ limitations?

> _PARTITIONTIME = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) from dataset.table1)

Answer (score 1):

Script is a possible solution.

```
DECLARE max_date DEFAULT (SELECT MAX(...) FROM ...);
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE _PARTITIONDATE = max_date;
```